# How do I display only a portion of a VARCHAR in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, varchar

My query returns a list of email address of users from a database. However instead of displaying the full email address, I only want it to display the provider. eg hotmail.com gmail.com etc. What would I need to add?
Edit: Im using MYSQL Workbench

Comment: Which dbms are you using? Some product specific differences in this string handlinh area...

Comment: You most likely want to use some sort of regular expression function, which is platform-specific.

Comment: Common approach: find position of `@` symbol in email address, then take part of address right to it. It's hard to say more without knowledge of your concrete DBMS.

Comment: Which database? MS SQL? MySQL? Oracle? PostgreSQL?

Comment: @BlackFrog Im using MySQL workbench

Comment: You probably want your **view** (or possibly your DAL) of your **application** to handle this. SQL shouldn't be used for this. Have SQL simply return the field in it's entirety and get the "domain part" of the string in your application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
substring(email from position('@' in email) + 1)
```

As defined by ANSI/ISO SQL:

```
<character position expression> ::=
POSITION <left paren> <character value expression 1> IN <character value expression 2>
[ USING <char length units> ] <right paren>
```

Supported by Mimer SQL.

Comment: Which database use the keyword **position**?  It would help in clarifying the answer.

Comment: @BlackFrog . . . Among others, MySQL, which would seem to be relevant.  But Postgres also supports it.  (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_position).